# Spark SQL - best way to programmatically loop over a table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have the following spark dataframe:

```
| Node_id | Parent_id |
|---------|-----------|
| 1       | NULL      |
| 2       |  1        |
| 3       | 1         |
| 4       | NULL      |
| 5       | 4         |
| 6       | NULL      |
| 7       | 6         |
| 8       | 3         |
```

This dataframe represents a tree structure consisting of several disjoint trees. Now, say that we have a list of nodes [8, 7], and we want to get a dataframe containing just the nodes that are roots of the trees containing the nodes in the list.The output looks like:

```
| Node_id | Parent_id |
|---------|-----------|
| 1       | NULL      |
| 6       | NULL      |
```

What would be the best (fastest) way to do this with spark queries and pyspark?

If I were doing this in plain SQL I would just do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Tmp 
    Node_id int,
    Parent_id int
INSERT INTO #Tmp Child_Nodes
SELECT @num = COUNT(*) FROM #Tmp WHERE Parent_id IS NOT NULL
WHILE @num > 0
    INSERT INTO #Tmp (
    SELECT
        p.Node_id
        p.Parent_id
    FROM
        #Tmp t
    LEFT-JOIN Nodes p
    ON t.Parent_id = p.Node_id)
    SELECT @num = COUNT(*) FROM #Tmp WHERE Parent_id IS NOT NULL
END
SELECT Node_id FROM #Tmp WHERE Parent_id IS NULL
```

Just wanted to know if there's a more spark-centric way of doing this using pyspark, beyond the obvious method of simply looping over the dataframe using python.

Comment: 4 is the root node, no? "select * where Paren_id is null" should work to get all the root node

Comment: @SomeshwarKale this would give 1, 4, 6 - I don't want root-nodes of nodes which are not in the table

Answer (score 0):

```
parent_nodes = spark.sql("select Parent_id from table_name where Node_id in [2,7]").distinct()
```

You can join the above dataframe with the table to get the Parent_id of those nodes as well.

Comment: This only works if the depth of any tree is no more than two levels. I have updated the example to give more explanation about the expected behavior.